# Arducam not working, mmal no data received from sensor error?

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, sensors

I am running the following command line to capture an image:

```
raspistill -o image.jpg
```

and I am getting this error message:

```
mmal: No data received from sensor. 
Check all connections, including the Sunny one on the camera board
```

I have tried the following steps:

Installed the camera in the port next to the DVI socket and made sure that both ends of the ribbon cable are seated.

Enabled the camera through a terminal on the PI via "sudo raspi-config"

Updated the Raspberry PI firmware through a terminal with "sudo rpi-update"

Increased the GPU memory available from the default of 128 to 144

Used "sudo vcgencmd get_camera" to make sure that the camera is detected. (output from this command is: supported=1 detected=1)

Checked that there is no other process accessing the camera: "sudo ps aux|grep raspi" the output was: pi 1097 0.0 0.0 4372 540 pts/0 S+ 09:09 0:00 grep --color=auto raspi

I have been working on this errors and I am not sure what the problem is.